# Can I request a truck route with a maximum gradient or elevation change?

Tags: here-api

I am setting up a routing service specific to certain types of trucks. I have been searching the HERE documentation for a way to specify a maximum gradient for the route, but cannot seem to find such a function. Am I missing something? Is this possible? My users indicate that 5% is a good threshold for certain trucks.

Answer (score 0):

Fleet Telematics API provides you the capability to handle such situation. PDE layer supports slope information in ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn. Below are some methods to achieve the above ask. You can pick any of the suggested ways depending on your usecase.  Hope you find it useful.

1. **Set fuel consumption on slope to very high number** – calculateroute.json method provides a requestParameter “customConsumptionDetails” in which the slope value could be set very high number that the route calculation tries to avoid such routes. Refer https://cle.api.here.com/swagger-ui.html?app_code=xxxx&app_id=xxxx#!/Routing_%26_Route_Matching/calculateRouteUsingGET
2. **Request for adas attributes and avoid slope links** -  Set requestParamater “attributes=ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn (SLOPES)” and get adas layer. Determine the links you would want to traverse and trigger same query setting “avoidLinks” requestParameter. Refer https://cle.api.here.com/swagger-ui.html?app_code=xxxx&app_id=xxxx#!/Routing_%26_Route_Matching/calculateRouteUsingGET. Also https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layer?region=WEU&release=18144&url_root=pde.api.here.com&layer=ADAS_ATTRIB_FC1 for explanation on ADAS attributes.
3. **Add custom overlay** – This method is used widely by our current customers. You can add a custom layer on top of Here Map layers where you can avoid links/roads where your trucks should pass through.  Read more on overlays - https://developer.here.com/documentation/custom-routing-extension/topics/resource-overlay.html